# How to split input text multiple times

Tags: python, input, text, structure

I have an input file that is structured in the following way: years are separated by a '-' studies by a '=' and students and their performance by a '\t'. My goal is to parse the input file to get to the numbers. When i finally do get to the numbers, I need the final two numbers that represent the performance of the students expressed in percentages. the problem is that when i split the input by, for example the hyphen, i get back a list and i dont know what to do at that point, since i cannot strip it another time since its now a list.
basically, it is a long list of names with a performance time in milliseconds, and then a performance expressed as a percentage, like this:
Frank Pierre    1398 81. It is the second number that i want to retrieve from all the different names in the list, since that number stands for a percentage.

I was already able to retrieve the numbers by using a for loop to go through all the items in the input file, and then appending them to a new list if they are integers, but the problem is that my solution uses the fact that all the numbers at the end are lower or equal to a hundred(since they are percentages) to finally remove them from the new list and add them to a new list of percentages. However, i want the program to work in a more general way for input files with the same structure.

Imagine a file with the same structure, but the first number after the name of the student in a couple cases is lower than 100. My program would recognize it as a percentage, since it is lower then a 100, but that is not the case! only the second number after the first stands for a percentage. This is why i think it would be better to parse the input file so that you get the numbers separated from everything else, and then retrieve the second number with, for example, using the index. I just dont have a clue how to do this.

If anyone has an idea how to get this done, that would be nice. The code has to be in python 2.7 and i cannot use any external modules, i have to define the functions myself. I just need to be able to get a list of the second numbers, so i can use them to make an analysis on them.

I currently have the following code:

```
'with open("statistics_input.txt", "r") as input:
    information = input.read()
    splitted = information.split('-')
first = splitted[0]'
```

the problem is that i now end up wih a list with 6 different indexes, one for each year and i have no idea how to further parse this. I have the first year as the variable first, but how can i now retrieve the numbers for that year and repeat that process for each year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far you have figured out the opening and reading the files, so I skip that part. Assuming your file contents is read in the variable `text`, this code:

```
data = {}
years = text.split('\n-')  # text -- is your source text

for y in years :
    year = y.split('\n') [0]
    subj = y.split('\n') [1:]

    data[year] = {}

    subject = 'none'
    for s in subj :
        if len(s) < 5 or s[0] == '=' :
            subject = s
            data[year][subject] = []
            continue
        name, result = s.split('\t')
        data[year][subject].append( (name, result) )

    print json.dumps( data, indent=4)
```

gives the following result:

```
{
    "1999": {
        "I": [
            [
                "Willem Jan van Steen", 
                "9859 77"
            ], 
            [
                "Guillaume Kielmann", 
                "5264 77"
            ], 
            [
                "Guillaume Bos", 
                "8200 6"
            ], 
            [
                "Matty Klop", 
                "9066 42"
            ], 
            [
                "Atze Klop", 
                "3318 45"
            ], 
            [
                "Sven Kielmann", 
                "1160 63"
            ], 
            [
                "Wartie Hijma", 
                "1904 65"
            ], 
            [
                "Matty Evers", 
                "2516 100"
            ], 
            [
                "Matty Bos", 
                "2941 99"
            ], 
            [
                "Pieter van der Ploeg", 
                "8873 80"
            ], 
            [
                "Jan Willem van Zeist", 
                "3934 95"
            ], 
            [
                "Thilo van Steen", 
                "9665 61"
            ], 
            [
                "Wan van Raamsdonk", 
                "1771 86"
            ], 
            [
                "Henri Fokkink", 
                "7484 59"
            ], 
            [
                "Jan Willem Evers", 
                "9709 82"
            ]
        ], 
        "=AI": [
            [
                "Sven Swarttouw", 
                "2604 73"
            ], 
            [
                "Eline van Raamsdonk", 
                "9771 60"
            ], 
            [
                "Herbert van der Ploeg", 
                "9325 41"
            ], 
            [
                "Eline Hijma", 
                "430 23"
            ], 
            [
                "Pieter Hijma", 
                "8203 65"
            ], 
            [
                "Eline Silvis Cividjian", 
                "2700 79"
            ]
        ], 
        "=W": [
            [
                "Guillaume Zeggers", 
                "290 47"
            ], 
            [
                "Natalia van Raamsdonk", 
                "2751 55"
            ], 
            [
                "Wartie Zeggers", 
                "3079 92"
            ], 
            [
                "Atze Swarttouw", 
                "9474 30"
            ], 
            [
                "Rene Pierre", 
                "2125 62"
            ], 
            [
                "Pieter van Mantgem", 
                "3023 67"
            ], 
            [
                "Jan Willem Hijma", 
                "7441 86"
            ]
        ], 
        "=BWI": [
            [
                "Rene Zeggers", 
                "7679 8"
            ], 
            [
                "Matty van Mantgem", 
                "7431 44"
            ], 
            [
                "Sven van Raamsdonk", 
                "7248 46"
            ], 
            [
                "Eline Pierre", 
                "5731 86"
            ], 
            [
                "Maarten Kielmann", 
                "7162 59"
            ], 
            [
                "Atze Zeggers", 
                "7065 72"
            ], 
            [
                "Eline van Mantgem", 
                "830 78"
            ], 
            [
                "Natalia van Steen", 
                "6321 49"
            ], 
            [
                "Frank van Raamsdonk", 
                "1380 31"
            ], 
            [
                "Pieter Bos", 
                "9639 94"
            ], 
            [
                "Andy Zeggers", 
                "5232 78"
            ], 
            [
                "Andy van Raamsdonk", 
                "1256 69"
            ], 
            [
                "Eline Gude", 
                "4101 40"
            ], 
            [
                "Matty Fokkink", 
                "9839 89"
            ], 
            [
                "Natalia Hijma", 
                "203 11"
            ], 
            [
                "Henri Bos", 
                "6728 66"
            ], 
            [
                "Guillaume van der Ploeg", 
                "9998 48"
            ], 
            [
                "Jan Willem van Steen", 
                "760 79"
            ], 
            [
                "Matty Pierre", 
                "337 96"
            ], 
            [
                "Wan Gude", 
                "3811 39"
            ]
        ], 
        "=ECTR": [
            [
                "Frank Swarttouw", 
                "6484 49"
            ], 
            [
                "Wan Hijma", 
                "9845 36"
            ], 
            [
                "Herbert Silvis Cividjian", 
                "1544 84"
            ], 
            [
                "Natalia Kielmann", 
                "646 21"
            ]
        ]
    }, 
    "2002": {
        "I": [
            [
                "Eline van Steen", 
                "7817 11"
            ], 
            [
                "Andy van Steen", 
                "9212 51"
            ], 
            [
                "Frank van Zeist", 
                "233 27"
            ], 
            [
                "Rene Swarttouw", 
                "5695 68"
            ], 
            [
                "Wan Bos", 
                "7039 29"
            ], 
            [
                "Eline van der Ploeg", 
                "4410 99"
            ], 
            [
                "Wartie van der Ploeg", 
                "2526 20"
            ], 
            [
                "Sven Bos", 
                "4694 98"
            ], 
            [
                "Wartie Swarttouw", 
                "5371 70"
            ], 
            [
                "Thilo van Zeist", 
                "10009 77"
            ], 
            [
                "Guillaume Fokkink", 
                "4125 86"
            ], 
            [
                "Atze Bos", 
                "4227 97"
            ], 
            [
                "Pieter Silvis Cividjian", 
                "9491 15"
            ], 
            [
                "Sven Evers", 
                "6994 41"
            ]
        ], 
        "=AI": [
            [
                "Matty van Steen", 
                "9702 40"
            ], 
            [
                "Thilo Silvis Cividjian", 
                "5553 42"
            ], 
            [
                "Herbert van Raamsdonk", 
                "6867 90"
            ], 
            [
                "Wartie Evers", 
                "2086 81"
            ], 
            [
                "Jan Willem Bos", 
                "1566 92"
            ], 
            [
                "Maarten van Mantgem", 
                "8960 92"
            ], 
            [
                "Sven van Zeist", 
                "8629 74"
            ], 
            [
                "Matty van Raamsdonk", 
                "496 41"
            ], 
            [
                "Willem Jan Evers", 
                "1853 11"
            ], 
            [
                "Guillaume van Zeist", 
                "9729 62"
            ], 
            [
                "Maarten Klop", 
                "8653 74"
            ], 
            [
                "Henri van der Ploeg", 
                "6755 39"
            ]
        ], 
        "=W": [
            [
                "Herbert Kielmann", 
                "2135 99"
            ], 
            [
                "Andy van Mantgem", 
                "8033 49"
            ], 
            [
                "Guillaume Gude", 
                "5356 52"
            ], 
            [
                "Herbert Bos", 
                "1435 47"
            ], 
            [
                "Pieter Gude", 
                "9460 36"
            ], 
            [
                "Jan Willem van der Ploeg", 
                "8403 25"
            ], 
            [
                "Wan van Mantgem", 
                "9672 68"
            ]
        ],
```

Here's how you print names and scores:

```
for year in data.values() :
    for subject in year.values() :
        for student in subject :
            print student[0], student[1].split()[1]  # only the last number
```

Comment: The code looks good! however, it is probably a little too complicated for the simple goal i am trying to accomplish. My only objective is to take each final number next to the students's name. I think the aproach of lxop which he posted below is the right one, but Im struggling to actually implement it. I am also not allowed to use external modules or methods such as json.dump.

Comment: `json.dump` is just to make a nice printout. you may iterate through the `data` dictionary and get the `name` and the `score` and print that out if you like

Comment: @noobmaster69 take a look at the loop at the end, this should print what you need. or you may change it if you like.

Comment: I have tried your code, but I get AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split' im not sure what causes this.I have removed the json part.

Comment: @noobmaster69 added missing loop =)

Comment: unfortunately, I get the error message AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'. I placed the loop you posted just below the json print statement, so at the bottom of the code. Is this correct, or am I supposed to place at inside another loop?

Comment: The code works in your part so I must be doing something wrong. Maybe you could post a comment with the complete code you have?

Comment: please, change `for student in subject.values()` into `for student in subject`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do what you are attempting. However, I have a couple of suggestions:

- after splitting by `'-'`, you have a list, as you say. However the entries in that list are all strings, and if you want to split into studies within a year's records, then you can take one of the strings in the list, and split it on `'='`. This will give you another list, but again the entries are strings, and can be handled appropriately.
- to get the last number in a line, you could split that line on spaces (`' '`), and take the last element of the resulting list. You would need to know that the line is a student (as opposed to a year or study marker), but it sounds like you might have figured that bit out already.

Comment: I feel like you didn't read the first bullet in my answer - each element in that list is a string, and you can split each of those however you like

Comment: Check (carefully) that you are splitting on the correct type of dash. There are several different ones that look quite similar - hyphen, em-dash, en-dash, etc. Also, based on your title, check that you are in fact calling `split()` and not `strip()`.

Comment: I just ran your exact code on your exact input file, and I got a list with 6 items in it. Did you copy-paste the code above or rewrite it?

Comment: Just to get back on that, I indeed have different lists when I print splitted, it was just hard to see since it was all on one line and i had a little difficulty spotting it, my bad.. However, I still dont have a clue on how to actually further parse this.

Comment: Do you know how to use loops and access individual entries in a list? If so, so can work with the individual lists to split by study as I suggested in the answer. When you get to the level of individual students, split by space and take the last entry to get the percentage (like in the answer above)

Comment: I am now up to the point where I have one of the years split by studies. However, the question is what now? since I cant split it anymore since its a list and I have all the individual studies as indexes now.

Comment: If you have 'one of the years split by studies', then you still have a list of strings - you can work with each string in _that_ list